# fix resolving SeekBarVolumizer class as it is not included in the android sdk

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My app won't compile because `android.preference.SeekBarVolumizer` cannot be resolved, i decompiled `android.jar` and couldn't find the class although this class is included in the android opensource code [HERE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.0_r6/core/java/android/preference/SeekBarVolumizer.java)

So, is there a way to ignore that error so i can compile the app,  or external libraries that i should import?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: just copy it's source into your new class, and use it

Comment: i tried that but this class imports more classes that is also not included in ```android.jar```

Comment: ok, now I see what is the problem: the class is anotated with `@hide`, which means that it won't be included into the development `android.jar`, but will be present on the device actually. You can try to find a modified `android.jar` which unhiddes all hidden classes/methods, or you can use it via reflection.

Comment: ok, thanks i found the modified ```android.jar``` in this github [LINK](https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api)